# Return rows that have a negative equivalent

Tags: sql-server

I have a non-normalized table with several columns. I would like to return all columns that have a positive number along with a negative number of the same value.

Example:

```
ID  |  Value
-------------
1   |  10
1   | -10
3   |  15
3   |  15
4   | -1
5   |  4
```

Current Output:

```
ID | Values
-------------
1  |  10
1  | -10
3  |  15
3  |  15
```

Desired Output:

```
ID | Value
-------------
1 |  10
1 | -10
```

I have made a windows function as seen below that will select absolute values that are the same, but this includes pairs where there are a positive number.

```
select Count(*) Over (Partition By DVN, [Tran Date], [Reference Number],Description,Vendor, Abs([Maintenance Expense])) As cnt , * 
    From WorkTemp.dbo.Customer2700Combine
    Where [Maintenance Expense] Is Not Null
Order By 1 Desc,DVN, [Tran Date], [Reference Number],Description,Vendor, Abs([NonRental Total])
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: In your example above, do you care about these values being part of the same ID?  or any value regardless of the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your requirement is by [ID], looking at your example, description and desired output, this is how I would do it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #sopg;

SELECT [ID],
       [VALUE]
INTO #sopg
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID,
           10 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS ID,
           -10 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID,
           15 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID,
           15 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS ID,
           -1 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS ID,
           4 AS VALUE
) x;

-- Assuming that one ID can only have maximum 2 rows (like your example above) and want this by ID

SELECT s.[ID],
       s.[VALUE]
FROM #sopg s
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT ID,
               SUM(VALUE) SumZero
        FROM #sopg
        GROUP BY ID
        HAVING SUM(VALUE) = 0
    ) SumZero ON SumZero.ID = s.ID

  -- Another way, assuming that ID can have more than 2 rows and different values

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #sopg2;

SELECT [ID],
       [VALUE]
INTO #sopg2
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID,
           10 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS ID,
           -10 AS VALUE
    UNION
        SELECT 1 AS ID,
           -9 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID,
           15 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID,
           15 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS ID,
           -1 AS VALUE
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS ID,
           4 AS VALUE
) x

SELECT a.[ID],
       a.[VALUE]
FROM #sopg2 a
INNER JOIN #sopg b ON b.ID = a.ID AND a.VALUE = -b.VALUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The second solution works perfectly, matching on a reversed value is very clever, I had no idea you could do that!

Comment: Yeah, you can basically do every conversion/transformation on the '=' part, by the way, if you copy and paste the test data that I put in my answer as part of your input test data in your question, people might upvote your answer as it will be easier to understand and reproduce. Cheers